# Mapping Vendor Item Number to Sales Lines, or clone existing field to a created one

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

I'm trying to customise a report with a value from an unrelated table. I can't figure out how to get an existing field to populate my custom field.

Specifically, I need the Vendor Item No. from Items (or Item Card) to be available on the Sales Lines table via the field I've created in a tableextension.

I'm not getting any code errors, and the extension installs successfully. `Vendor Item No.` is a system default field on Items.

Within `tableextension`, I've tried using CalcFormula, TableRelation, and a DataTransfer procedure to make `Vendor Item Custom Table` to equal `Vendor Item No.`.

I only get a blank value, with no errors:

```
tableextension 50102 SalesLineVendorTble extends "Sales Line"
{
    fields
    {
        //orginal field on Items is (32; "Vendor Item No."; Text[50])
        //Works to insert new field, no linked data
        field(999; "Vendor Item Custom Table"; Text[50])
        {
            //TableRelation, doesn't work
            DataClassification = ToBeClassified; //DataClassification or FlowField, choose 1
            TableRelation = Item."Vendor Item No." where("No." = field("No."));

            //CalcFormula via FlowField
            //FieldClass = FlowField; //DataClassification or FlowField, choose 1
            //CalcFormula = lookup(item."Vendor Item No." where("No." = field("No.")));
        }
    }

//Below is procedure trying to link via multiple methods
    /*
        local procedure CopyVendorItemNum()
        var
            dt: datatransfer;
            dest: Record "Sales Line";
            src: Record Item;
        begin
            //define SalesLine.CustomField is same as Item.VendorNumber
                //did not work
            //rec."Vendor Item Custom Table" := src."Vendor Item No.";

            //Set up datatransfer, link tables and copy fields
                //did not work
            dt.SetTables(Database::Item, Database::"Sales Line");
            dt.AddFieldValue(src.FieldNo("Vendor Item No."), dest.Fieldno("Vendor Item Custom Table"));
            dt.AddJoin(src.FieldNo("No."), dest.FieldNo("No."));
            dt.CopyFields();
        end;
    */
}
```

Inserting the field to a report's dataset is working, but with no value on the sales line, nothing shows up here. Seems fine here

```
reportextension 50101 PickAddVendor extends "Pick Instruction"
{
    RDLCLayout = './CustomReport.rdlc';
    dataset
    {
        add("Sales Line")
        {
            //factoryCodeTable is name for internal use
            //Vendor Item Custom Table is custom Field
            column("FactoryCodeTable"; "Vendor Item Custom Table")
            { }
} } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the table extension. You can solve it on the report extension it self.

You need to create a global variable to hold the value and then use that variable as the source of your added column.

A final solution could look something like this:

```
reportextension 50101 "PickAddVendor" extends "Pick Instruction"
{
    RDLCLayout = './CustomReport.rdlc';

    dataset
    {
        add("Sales Line")
        {
            column(FactoryCodeTable; FactoryCodeTable) { }
        }

        modify("Sales Line") 
        {
            trigger OnAfterAfterGetRecord()
            begin
                GetFactoryCodeTable("Sales Line");
            end;
        }
    }

    local procedure GetFactoryCodeTable(SalesLine: Record "Sales Line")
    var
        Item: Record Item;
    begin
        // Reset the variable
        Clear(FactoryCodeTable);

        // Make sure it is an Item line
        if SalesLine.Type <> SalesLine.Type::Item then
            exit;

        // Get the Item - exit if it does not exist
        if not Item.Get(SalesLine."No.") then
            exit;

        // Set the variable
        FactoryCodeTable := Item."Vendor Item No.";
    end;

    var
        FactoryCodeTable: Code[20];
}
```

---

**Bonus Information**

If you want to use the field from your table extension, then the correct method would be a `FlowField` which you would then need to calculate in the report extension using `SetAutoCalcFields` in `OnAfterOnPreDataItem`.

`TableRelation` basicly just set the foreign key of the field.

`DataTransfer` is reserved for `Install` and `Upgrade` codeunits.

Comment: Works perfect. Didn't realise I need to trigger the procedure run, but makes total sense.